Better glue for outdoor furniture
It's been said Titebond3 is good but not great for outdoor furniture. Previously I had used resorcinol glue for outside projects but that great glue has become hard to find. A few years back Franklin International slipped 'not for structural applications' on their label (I don't know if that is still on the label).  Turns out yellow glues such as Titebond3 may allow creep.  I currently use Titebond3 for outdoor projects however, the question I ask here:  Is there a reasonable alternative?

Epoxy is good, but I've never had an issue with TB3 for outdoor furniture personally.

According to @Graphus in comment on a different question, Titebond3 is acceptable for outdoor projects but, not the best selection.  That has been my experience as well except when used in dovetail joints of cedar planter boxes after 2 years use.  Those boxes were filled with wet soil and live plant roots.

I can't speak for Graphus, but I think he was objecting to TB for reasons other than performance if I"m thinking of the same comments that you are. I know many instances of TB3 (and even TB2) in outdoor environments where it does just fine.  Other than the glue itself, the surfaces (composition, preparation, geometry, etc.) and any additional joinery/fasteners are very significant here. With any glue/adhesive you have to meet it half way and provide an application environment where it has the best chances of success.

Asking for a "reasonable" alternative is a loaded question, since of course what's reasonable for one person is not reasonable for another. The simple difficulty of acquiring something (hard to find, wait time, even delivery cost) is not a reasonable objection for some users who want to use what they want to use, damn the torpedoes and all that :-) While of course any of those specific reasons could be big deal for many others who are too busy, CBA etc.

Now, that aside, how much research did you do before asking this....? The SE model requires prior research and at least some evidence of same should be listed in the body of the Q. Even without looking I'm sure you realise that there is already a wealth of information out there on weatherproof adhesives, with the 'main two' being widely recommended everywhere when the subject comes up. You could do that research now and self-answer your Q.

@graphus - research?  years of it I'm afraid.  Two events in the past made me spend hours looking for alternatives.  When I couldn't find resorcinol (industrial gallons excepted) - many hours then.  When Franklin International first added that 'not for structural applications' to the label on Titebond there was hours gone into understanding creep.  After purchasing a home with wood I-beam type joists that had been glues with a resorcinol glue again, hours of  research.  Way too much 'requires prior research' comments going on this site.  Let's all get back to answering questions presented.

As to proof of research in every question - this one did mention Franklin Internation's comment and discovering creep is involved. Let's all get back to woodworking which includes sharing what we do know and not being afraid to ask what we don't.

@quill, you seem to be intimating there's something like nitpicking going on here but that's far from the case; you'll notice my mention of that was a second, separate, Comment after addressing the query. Regardless if it's commonly absent (as it is) this is a requirement, not merely a suggestion — just look for the word research in the Help. Heck, the classic reason to downvote is "does not show any research effort" (my emphasis); it's not helping that most no longer see this because they're accessing SE on a phone or tablet and the mobile version doesn't have the popups for the arrows.

Furthermore, see, Answer well-asked questions in How do I write a good answer?.
